# Set Border Width of a Group using Expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am developing a multi-grouped report. Base on the level of a group, I am to set the bottom border width to 2pt else 1pt. I only know how to set the default for all groups. I have googled and tried various expressions but unable to get around the requirement.
          An example of what I want to achieve is shown in the image below
    [image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could evaluate the scope on a group and set a row(s) bottom border accordingly.

If you right-click a row I assume you could apply the following in an expression:

```
<For the Border.BorderWidth.Bottom property of the detail or row group> 

=IIF(Level("MyGroup")=0,"1pt","2pt")
```

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/users/611545/ross-bush. When I pasted
       =Border.BorderWidth.Bottom = IIF(Level("MyGroupName")=0,"1pt","2pt") 
 I got the error "Border not declared"

Comment: I updated the answer, I mean navigate to the row and select the object explorer and then select border bottom of the row and set this in the expression.

Comment: Yea, it was in the property pane that I did the setting.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Ross Bush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254379/2358222) seems to be correct. Though I would use `Choose` as it gives more options should you need more width.

[image: You should edit the expression for width]

I've used 10pt and 20pt so the difference is easily visible for this example.